# How do I compute the feedforward terms in a control law using Matlab?

Tags: mobile-robot, control, matlab, simulation

I have the following situation. I have computed the linear and angular velocity which are the controls for a mobile robot, which have the form:

$v_d=v_{fb}+v_{ff}$

$\omega_d=\omega_{fb}+\omega_{ff}$

now, I would like to define the acceleration controls, and I know that I can do it in the following way:

$a_v=(v_d-v_{actual})+\dot{v_d}$

$a_\omega=(\omega_d-\omega_{actual})+\dot{\omega_d}$

I would like to do this using Matlab\Simulink. This code is inside a Matlab function clock.

my question is:

**Is there a way I can compute the feedforward terms $\dot{v_d}$ and $\dot{\omega_d}$ without computing them manually?**

I would like to avoid to compute them manually since their expression is really complicated and it is almost impossible to not make mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calculating $v_d$ and $\omega_d$? Simulink has a [derivative block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/derivative.html), have you tried using that?